# Protractor Test cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor

I am new to protractor e2e testing. and i have written my first test code.. I would like to know your feedback and ways i can improve it.

```
  describe("Map feedback Automation",function(){
it("Check if the Url works ",function()
{
    browser.get(browser.params.url);
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("report");

});it("test browser should reach report road option",function()
{
    element.all(by.css('div[ng-click="setLocation(\'report_road\')"]')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("report_road");

});


it("test browser should reach report road missing",function()
{
    element.all(by.css('div[ ng-click="mapFeedBack.editObject= mapFeedBack.createMapObjectModel();setLocation(mapFeedBack.noMap?\'road_new\':\'choose_location_road_new/road_new\')"]')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("choose_location_road_new/road_new");
    browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);
});


it("test browser should zoom on map ",function() //manual 
{


element.all(by.css('div[ng-click="zoomIn()"]')).click();            
browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);
element.all(by.css('div[ng-click="zoomIn()"]')).click();
browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);


element.all(by.css('div[ng-click="zoomIn()"]')).click();
browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);

element.all(by.css('div[ng-click="zoomIn()"]')).click();
browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);


}); 

it("Should click on ok option",function()
{

    element(by.buttonText('OK')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("road_new");

}); 
it("test browser should reach report road option",function()
{

    browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("road_new");

}); 



it("should  enter a road name",function() 
{       

 browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);

 var testroadname = browser.params.testroadname;


 element(by.model("mapFeedBack.editObject.roadName")).sendKeys(testroadname);
browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);




});


    it("should check the type of road is highway",function()  //spec3
{

element(by.model("mapFeedBack.editObject[attrs.select].selected")).$("[value='string:app.road.roadType.highway']").click();




});


    it("should  submmit the map feedback",function() 
{       

element(by.css('button[ng-click="onSubmit({reportType: reportType})"]')).click();
    browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);
});});
```

A colleague of mine told me to remove the delay

```
browser.sleep(browser.params.sleeptime);
```

and add some event when the zoom in button is clicked. can you suggest me the ways i can achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they say, every code has it's own [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). One the worst smells produced by Protractor-specific code is the use of `browser.sleep()` to tackle timing issues. `browser.sleep()` calls usually are making the tests much slower than it is needed and occasionally don't add enough of a delay to make a test pass making the author of the code increase the sleep delay  which again makes a test even more slower. And, by the way, there is a related third-party [`ESLint` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-browser-sleep.md) that would help to prevent you from having `browser.sleep()` in the e2e codebase.

A more robust alternative to having a hardcode delay, is to use [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and a set of built-in [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions). The main advantage here is that *`browser.wait()` would wait as long as it is necessary* continuously checking the state of the expected condition.

For example, in your case, you might make the world a better place to do test automation by using `elementToBeClickable` condition:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.id("myid"));

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 10000);
elm.click();
```

Here, `Protractor` would wait *up to* (`up to` is really what makes the difference) 10 seconds (yes, you still need a timeout value) and would raise a Timeout Exception if the element would not become clickable.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I have learnt a lot for it!!

Comment: Also Alecxe can you share any link for learning protractor.. it would help me a lot to learn protractor!!

Comment: @Jatin sure, there is that [official tutorial](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial), which would be a good place to start. Also, go through questions in a `protractor` tag here on SO, sort them by votes and study - you would see the common problems users tackle with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wait for the button to be visible using the following wait command:

```
var btn = element(by.css("mycss"));
browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(btn), 5000);
btn.click();
```

Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.