# protractor list filter test fails, counting 0 instead of expected number

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor, angularjs-filter

Protractor test fails on 4 tests, counting 0 instead of expected number of filtered values from list. However the filter in the actual program works fine.

The tests run. Values are entered in the search textboxduring the test. What is wrong with the test? How to solve?

Here's the test:

```js
'use strict';

// Angular E2E Testing Guide:
// https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

describe('LLO 2016', function() {

  describe('edit-leerling', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('index.html#/leerlingen');
    });

    it('should filter the leerlingen list as a user types into the search box', function() {
      var editLeerling = element.all(by.repeater('(id, leerling) in leerlingen'));
      var query = element(by.model('mentorQuery'));

      expect(editLeerling.count()).toBe(248);

      query.sendKeys('5H');
      expect(editLeerling.count()).toBe(163);

      query.clear();
      query.sendKeys('6V');
      expect(editLeerling.count()).toBe(85);

      query.clear();
      query.sendKeys('WIND');
      expect(editLeerling.count()).toBe(22);
    });

  });

});
```

And here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Leerlingenlijst</h3><br />
  Zoeken: <input ng-model="mentorQuery" />
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th>Nr.</th>
        <th>Mentor</th>
        <th>Klas</th>
        <th>Leerling Naam</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="(id, leerling) in leerlingen | filter: mentorQuery">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <td><span>{{leerling.leerlingNummer}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{leerling.leerlingMentor}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{leerling.leerlingKlas}}</span></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="leerling.leerlingNaam"></td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="update({id: id})">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="remove({id: id})">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see the first `expect()` (before any filtering) failing as well?

Comment: @alecxe Yes, also 0

Comment: Okay, quick check what if you locate the results this way: `var editLeerling = $$('tr[ng-repeat*="(id, leerling) in leerlingen"]);` - any difference?

Comment: @alecxe No difference. Should I add delay so the page has the time to load the 248 lines?

Comment: Gotcha. Okay. Let's add `browser.sleep(5000)` before the first expectation (for debugging only - this is not a reliable solution anyway). Does it help?

Comment: @alecxe That helps, all tests pass now! How to make that into a relaiable solution? I tried browser.get('index.html#/leerlingen').then(function() {       it('should ... but then is says 'no specs found'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, we've figured out in comments, that this is a *timing issue* - the search results are not yet loaded when you make the expectations.

`browser.sleep()` itself is not a reliable solution (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647077/771848) why). You need a `browser.wait()` and a condition to wait for. At the very least we can check for the presence of at least one search result:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.repeater('(id, leerling) in leerlingen'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);

var editLeerling = element.all(by.repeater('(id, leerling) in leerlingen'));
var query = element(by.model('mentorQuery'));

expect(editLeerling.count()).toBe(248);

// ...
```